# $L^1$ estimate about a kind of fourier restriction type function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, harmonic-functions, fourier-restriction

> Consider a function $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$, and define its Fourier transform by
> $$\hat f(\xi_1,\xi_2)=\int_{\mathbb R\times\mathbb R}f(x_1,x_2)e^{-i(x_1\ \xi_2+x_2\  \xi_2)}\,dx_1\,dx_2, \qquad \xi_1,\xi_2\in\mathbb R.$$
> For each $t>0$, define
> $$g(t,x)=\int_{\mathbb R}\hat f(\xi,\xi t) e^{ix\xi}\,d\xi,\qquad x\in\mathbb R.$$
> Show that $\|g(t,\cdot)\|_{L^1(\mathbb R^1)}\lesssim \|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb R^2)}$.

This question comes from the formula $(3.1)$ in  Lemma $3.1$ of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.08580.pdf), where all the $\mathbb R$ above are replaced by $\mathbb R^3$. The authors said in the paper that "The inequality $(3.1)$ is clear", but I cannot figure the proof.

I can prove an $L^2$ variant as follows:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb R}|g(t,x)|^2\,dx&\approx \int_{\mathbb R}|\hat f(\xi,\xi t)|^2\,d\xi\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R}\langle (\xi,\xi t)\rangle^{-1-2\varepsilon}\left|\langle (\xi,\xi t)\rangle^{\frac12+\varepsilon}\hat f(\xi,\xi t)\right|^2\,d\xi\\
&\lesssim \|\langle \nabla\rangle^{1/2+\varepsilon} f\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^2)}^2\int_{\mathbb R}\langle (\xi,\xi t)\rangle^{-1-2\varepsilon}\,d\xi\\
&\lesssim_\varepsilon \langle t\rangle^{-1}\|\langle \nabla\rangle^{1/2+\varepsilon} f\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^2)}^2,
\end{align*}
for any $\varepsilon>0$.

However, as for the original problem, I do not know how to start.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me that what you've written is the same as what's in the paper; it seems there's an extra Fourier transform in your definition of $g$ as opposed to their $\mathfrak{H}$. In their setting, the case $\sigma=0$ in (3.1) is simply Fubini's theorem and translation invariance.

Comment: @Jose27 Aha! You're right! I was thinking that the $L^2$ and $L^\infty$ estimates would be easier to verify, so I proved the latter two inequalities first, where I didn't use the exact definition of $\mathfrak{H}$. So I just simply thought here we can do something similar. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Jose27's comments, which motivated me to write down the proof here.

Define
$$h(t,x)=\int_\mathbb R f(x-tv,v)\,dv,\qquad t>0, x\in\mathbb R.$$
Denoting the Fourier transform of $h$ with respect to $x$ as $\hat h(t,\xi)$, then
$$\hat h(t,\xi)=\hat f(\xi, \xi t).$$
This implies that $h$ equals to $g$ multiplied by a constant that dosen't depend on $t$. A simply application of Fubini implies the estimate
$$\|h(t,\cdot)\|_{L^1(\mathbb R^1)}\le \|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb R^2)},$$
which gives the desired $L^1$ estimate on $g$.

*Remark:* For any $\sigma\in\mathbb R$, define
$$g_\sigma(t,x)=\int_\mathbb R \langle(\xi, \xi t)\rangle^\sigma \hat f(\xi,\xi t)e^{ix\xi}\,d\xi,\qquad t\in\mathbb R, x\in\mathbb R.$$
Using a similar argument, we can also prove
$$\|g_\sigma(t,\cdot)\|_{L^1(\mathbb R^1)}\lesssim \|\langle\nabla\rangle^\sigma f\|_{L^1(\mathbb R^2)}.$$